# Does the word "die Programmatik" have a plural form?

Tags: grammatical-number

According to en.pons.com, there is no plural. But canoo.net says the plural is *die Programmatiken*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, [a Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22programmatiken%22) currently yields 13700 results, so the plural obviously exists. A few examples from the first results:

> Exzellenz und/oder Chancengleichheit der Geschlechter: Nationale Programmatiken und diskursive Praktiken an Universitäten (Deutschland und Schweiz)
>   Soziale Arbeit in der unternehmerischen Stadt: Kontexte, Programmatiken, Ausblicke
>   Erkenntnisgewinnung und Erkenntnisveränderung in neueren wissenschaftlichen Programmatiken

The plural is rare, though, as [*Duden* notes](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Programmatik), too. Judging from the examples found via the above web search, its use appears to be restricted to certain academic fields.